# does dark mass/energy change cosmic red shift

Tags: redshift

Virtually all cosmology is based on the observation that galactic light is red-shifted.  The Hubble Law defines that the red-shift is proportional to distance photons traveled.  Further, this observation is specifically explained by the general relativistic expansion of space-time.  No other explanation is accepted of any alternate or additional reason(s) that might reduce the energy (red-shift) of galactic photons observe.  Can other factors describe the decrease in the frequency of these ancient photons?
It appears that universe contains a large amount of dark matter and dark energy - which is rather difficult to define its relationship with known mass/energy through current general relativity and quantum mechanics.   What of these concepts PREVENT a photon’s energy from being reduced by incremental interaction with dark matter/energy – that occurred over immense distances and vast eons?   Can other additional (hidden) variables influence the interpretation that expansion of space-time is the singular explanation of the galactic red-shifting?  Obviously, any additional factor would require revision of certain aspects of the accepted cosmology paradigm.

Comment: You can read here about why this idea is discredited: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_light

Comment: Thank you G. Smith regarding "Tired Light" hypothesis created 100 years ago.  My question, however, is somewhat different.  It regards interaction with dark mass/energy, not the more conventional mass/energy.  I understand that the reaction of photons with dark stuff in not completely understood.  But based on what is known about dark stuff, is there a theory that prevents any interaction between known photons and the dark stuff.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Dark energy is said to be speeding up the expansion of the universe. The faster the expansion the greater the redshift. Dark matter, on the other hand, forms an integral part of galactic mass and always has done. This galactic mass forms a large part of the mass of the universe, and until the advent of dark energy it was believed that the mass of the universe would eventually slow the expansion to a standstill, at which point it would collapse on itself and transform the redshift into a blueshift. We would thus have a Big Bang - Big Crunch universe. followed, many believed, by a Big Bounce,so the universe would oscillate between the two states for ever. So will matter and dark matter, which are trying to slow the expansion down, eventually triumph, or will dark energy increase the rate of expansion and prevent this from happening? At present dark energy seems to be winning, but we can't be sure. New data or a new interpretation of old data may find we are slowing down after all. For this reason the Big Bang - Big Crunch model hasn't been entirely abandoned by some cosmologists, but their faith is wavering. Other factors which are at present hidden variables may be influencing the redshift that we observe, so we await further developments in this field.

Comment: Michael Walsby, thank you for you thoughts.  Clearly, I am pretty new on what is known about the dark stuff.  I appreciate your answer, but it is not clear what property. observation, hypothesis or theory prevents dark stuff to interact with photons.

Comment: We have yet to find out what dark matter is. I'm not convinced that it's composed of Weakly Interacting Massive Particles. (WIMPs).